# остановить auto reload

Tags: javascript, html

На странице имеется счётчик:

```html
<div id="r" class="value alert">98 724</div>
```

И при достижении определённого результата страница автоматически обновляется. Как заморозить счётчик с помощью консоли хрома? Или как с помощью консоли запретить авто обновление страницы?

P.S.: Получилось вызвать ошибки в js скриптах и счётчики остановились но после f5 возобновились. Как через консоль отключить js скрипты?

Comment: От чего зависит счётчик? Если обработчик счётчика работает в клиентской части - просто удалите этот элемент или присвойте ему значение 0.

Comment: Я не знаю кто им управляет но работает он в клиентской части. Удалять элемент каждый раз не вариант. Разве нельзя ввести в консоли что то вроде window.stop(); ?

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать такое решение:

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function(e) { 
    return "Bzzz..."
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Или на js:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
    return "Bzzz..."
    e.preventDefault();
};
```

Comment: Это срабатывает 1 раз. После ручного обновления страницы опять происходит авто обновление.

Comment: @SergeyZzz это работает после добавления кода в консоль. Если Вы обновили сами, или заново перезашли, то логично, что необходимо заново прописать код. Ведь у Вас доступа к серверу нет, как же Вы хотите на определённой странице навсегда запретить перезагрузку? Так не бывает.

Comment: @SergeyZzz можете воспользоваться `injector`, который сам будет добавлять автоматически на страницу этот код. А так чтобы один раз прописать на сайте код и он навсегда запрещал перезагрузку(без доступа к коду) - такого не бывает.

Comment: Мне нужно на вкладке запретить перезагрузку а не на странице.

Comment: @SergeyZzz разница в чём? Есть ресурс. У Вас доступа к этому ресурсу нет. Вы можете запретить обновление страницы на определённой вкладке используя код выше! Просто прописав его в консоли. Откроете вторую вкладку с таким же адресом - там всё будет работать как и без кода! Зачем обновлять вручную страницу, если Вы хотите запретить обновление, что за глупости????

Comment: Если обновить страницу в этой вкладке или перейти на другую страницу в пределах сайта то запрет перестаёт работать.

Comment: Я хочу запретить обновление так как пропадают данные введённые на форме из за авто обновления. Я хочу что то прописать в консоли что бы на вкладке прекратились обновления без моего нажатия. Я хочу запретить не обновления а АВТО обновления.

Comment: @SergeyZzz это же логично!!! Если Вы переходите на другую вкладку - у Вас загружается другой DOM или ресурс, конечно не будет работать!!! У Вас вообще есть хоть какое-то понимание как работают ресурсы в интернете???

Comment: Я не на вкладку другую перехожу а на другую страницу на вкладке. Разве нет элементарного способа запретить приём HTML без команды пользователя???

Comment: @SergeyZzz остается только один вариант - писать плагин, пусть он автоматом все и очищает.